# jquery parsing xml with \n

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm using jquery to parse some xml. However, the xml has line breaks and spaces in it. E.g.

some item

instead of

some item

When I get the text() of the node, I get "\n         some item       \n"

Is there some way I get either strip this white space after text() or just get jquery to ignore it while parsing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it: jQuery.trim()